# Kivy screenshot a Layout or id

Tags: android, kivy, python-3.5, kivy-language

So i have a small app and I want to do a screenshot of a whole BoxLayout and omitting the other pieces of the parent layouts.

**NOTE: This is for an android app**

basically i have something like this:

```
    BoxLayout:
        id: image_area
        size_hint_y: 600
        Image:
            source: root.image_source
            size: self.size
            DragText:
                background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
                foreground_color: (255,255,255,255)
                multiline: True
                height: self.minimum_height
                width: '400dp'
                center: self.parent.center
                text: 'Before'
                font_size: '60px'
        Image:
            source: root.image_source2
            DragText:
                background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
                foreground_color: (255,255,255,255)
                multiline: True
                height: self.minimum_height
                width: '400dp'
                center: self.parent.center
                text: 'After'
                font_size: '60px'
```

I have other Layouts above this one and even a parent is a box layout but i just want to screenshot this layout and i'm having trouble with this.

I tried:

```
def screenshot(self, widget):
    widget.export_to_png('{0}.png'.format(datetime.now()))
```

But it doesn't work, any idea how i could do this?

I forgot to specify this, the button that activates the screenshot looks like this

```
        Button:
            size_hint_x: 2
            text: 'Save'
            on_release: root.screenshot(image_area)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. Directly from kvlang, or like you tried, with a method in python.
I will show you both examples.

Directly from kvlang:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string('''


<MyLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        text: "Label1 in outer box"

    BoxLayout:
        id: myexport
        Label:
            text: "Label in inner layout"

    Label:
        text: "Label2 in outer box"
    Button:
        text: "Button in outer, to export"
        on_release: myexport.export_to_png("test.png")


''')

class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


if __name__=='__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

With method:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string('''


<MyLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        text: "Label1 in outer box"

    BoxLayout:
        id: myexport
        Label:
            text: "Label in inner layout"

    Label:
        text: "Label2 in outer box"
    Button:
        text: "Button in outer, to export"
        on_release: root.export()


''')

class MyLayout(BoxLayout):

    def export(self,*args):
        self.ids.myexport.export_to_png("test2.png")


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


if __name__=='__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped

Comment: @Nick you are wellcome